# Text align css in display : inline always go to right align

Tags: html, css

Here is my fiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/dn26r0xz/,

```
<div class="box">V</div><span class="notice">OK</span>
            <div class="box">B</div><span class="notice">BROKEN</span>
            <div class="box">C</div><span class="notice">CUT</span>
            <div class="box">BE</div><span class="notice">BENT</span>
            <div class="box">D</div><span class="notice">DENT</span>
            <div class="box">H</div><span class="notice">HOLE</span>
            <div class="box">M</div><span class="notice">MISSING</span>
            <div class="box">S</div><span class="notice">SCRATCH</span>
            <div class="box">Z</div><span class="notice">MODIFICATION</span>

.box{
            display: inline;
            width: 5px;
            height: 20px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding-left: 20px;
            margin-top: 10px;    
            margin-left: 10px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .notice{
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 8px;
            margin-top: 0;
            margin-right: 2px;
            margin-left: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
```

How can I make it to center on those box like V, B, and so on ?. I use text-align but its not working.
For help, it so appreciated

Comment: Using `padding-left: 20px` along with `text-align: center` will push your text 20 pixels left of center. The best solution for this would be to remove the `text-align: center` and add padding to the right side as well.

Answer (score 0):

please write this way:

```
.box{
     display: inline-block;
     width: auto;
     height: 20px;
     border: 1px solid black;
     padding-left: 10px;
     padding-right:10px;
     margin-top: 10px;    
     margin-left: 10px;
     text-align: center;
     }
```

[click here](https://jsfiddle.net/dn26r0xz/10/) for demo

Answer (score 0):

Change the CSS like this:

```
       .box{
            display: inline-block;
            width: 25px;
            height: 20px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 3px 5px 0;
            margin-top: 10px;    
            margin-left: 10px;
            text-align: center;
        }
```

width was much too small (5px), and I also changed the padding a bit.

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zbny6ry7/